# Creating a scheduled task in an Access/SharePoint web app

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

At some point in time I'm going to build a system for my school that informs parents of their homework for a given day, and I'm considering my options. A Microsoft Access Web App through SharePoint seems like a compelling option for a number of reasons, but I'd like to build a system that E-mails homework reports to parents at a set time every day.
Is it possible to schedule this under a web app? Would I be able to do it if I just had the database open on a computer full-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at this point in time Access 2013 web applications don’t have an email ability.

Of course the other issue is Access web running on office 365 does not allow anonymous users. So if the web system is to allow parents to logon, then you using the wrong tool. And without email ability built in, then again you using the wrong tool.

And if you don’t need parents to logon and use the web site, the why bother with Access web services then?

Access 2010 web applications do have email ability, but I would not invest long term development for 2010 web since it been deprecated and superseded by Access 2013 web.

You could consider creating a desktop Access applications that uses linked tables to the web application and thus schedule + send emails from the desktop application. This setup is in fact allowed for both Access 2010 web and 2013 based applications.

So the data + web part of the application that runs on Access web services could be built on office 365. However, since the web part is not needed nor appropriate and you don’t mention if anyone needs to use the web site except for the ONE person typing in some emails to send, then it is unlikely that Access web services makes sense (unless you have your own SharePoint server – that changes everything).

So “most” use Access web publishing with office 365, but hat setup does not support nor allow anonymous users – they must have an office 365 logon, or have a live id.

In fact you not mentioned or noted why you think a web application as opposed to some desktop application to send out some emails is a better choice? Web based really don’t make sense unless need a system in which parents are to logon to the web site.

So there is no scheduling mechanisms for WEB Based Access applications. And even WORSE is Access 2013 web applications do not have ANY email support. So no email ability quite much burns the bridge on using Access 2013 web applications for emailing.

So it not clear at all why you think web based systems would at all be useful for sending out some emails unless that web site and system is to interact with parents who have to sign up and maintain their emails on line.

Comment: Thanks for all the information; I've realised that I'd been making a few assumptions that I now understand to be false. I wanted to upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is with a scheduled task on a computer with Access installed. All you need it a .bat file like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "\\DatabaseServer\DatabasePath\MyDatabase.accdb" /x MacroToRunOnSchedule
```

Then create a macro that calls a VBA function that runs your scheduled task. Don't forget to make the database close as the last act of that task. There are several ways to send e-mail from access depending on what you will use as mail server.

Ideally install Access on your server or alternatively use a workstation that stays always on and does not got o sleep.

Comment: The poster is asking about AWS (Access Web Services). These applications are not desktop based and are 100% browser based. They don't need nor use Access desktop and they don't have VBA either. So your answer does not apply to Access web applications that run on SharePoint. SharePoint does have email ability, but Access web applications cannot use that feature at this point in time.

Comment: Nonetheless, it's a neat little technique that might come in handy later. Thanks for the answer; I don't have the reputation to be able to upvote yet.